# Prove that $\lim\limits_{n\to+\infty }u_n=+\infty $ using Fatou's lemma

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

We define :

> $$u_{n}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}{\biggl(1-\frac{1}{n}\biggr)^{\!k}},\qquad v_n=\ln(n) -u_n$$

Using Fatou's lemma , I have to prove  that :

$\lim\limits_{n\to+\infty }u_n=+\infty $

---

My idea :

We know that :

$$\ln(n) = \int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x}\mathbf 1_{[1,n]}(x)\,dx$$

We define :

$$u_n = \int_1^\infty f_n(x)\mathbf 1_{[1,n]}(x)\,dx$$

With :

$$f_n(x) = \frac{1}{k}(1-\frac{1}{n})^k \text{ if }x\in [k;k+1[,~k\in [\mkern-2mu[1,n]\mkern-2mu]$$

$$f_n(x) = 0 \text{ if } x \geq n+1$$

Then :

$$v_n = \int_1^\infty \biggl(\frac{1}{x}-f_n(x)\biggr)\mathbf 1_{[1,n]}(x)\,dx$$

And define also ,

$$g_n(x) = \biggl(\frac{1}{x}-f_n(x)\biggr)\mathbf 1_{[1,n]}(x)$$

I still have no clue for  .. how can I apply Fatou's lemma . Thanks in advance any help would be highly appreciated .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}u_{n}&=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(1-\dfrac{1}{n}\right)^{k}\\
&=\liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(1-\dfrac{1}{n}\right)^{k}\\
&=\liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\chi_{1\leq k\leq n}\left(1-\dfrac{1}{n}\right)^{k}\\
&\geq\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty}\chi_{1\leq k\leq n}\left(1-\dfrac{1}{n}\right)^{k}\\\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}1^{k}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}1\\
&=\infty.
\end{align*}

Note that $\left\{\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(1-\dfrac{1}{n}\right)^{k}\right\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is an increasing sequence of $n$.

Comment: I don't see exactly what is $\chi$

Comment: @Simba27 It's the indicator function (which you denotes by $1_{1\le k\le n}$).

Comment: Thanks @CélioAugusto